# Java: Import at run-time

Tags: java, generics, data-structures, visualization

I'm trying to make Data Structure Visualization Library for classes used in a course.
I want student to import them to their code and use them as they edit the collection classes.
I know the name of classes they are going to use, but the implementation could be different form student to another.

```
public class SLLVisualizer extends JFrame {
public SLLVisualizer(SLL<T> sll) {
}   
}
```

Above is the constructor I'm trying to make. But it gives me Syntax error due to unknown SLL type

Comment: Seems like you need an **interface** that your students implement. You know, an interface that defines the *contract*, i.e. methods, that your students classes must implement.

Comment: So do you have an interface called `SLL` that the students will implement?  Can you make this compile by importing that interface?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that the class SSL doesn't know what type you want to assign SSL. SSL is a generic class. Try rather this:

```
public class SSLVisualizer extends jFrame {
    public SSLVisualizer (SSL<String> ssl) {

    }
}
```

If you want to be able to put in any data type of SSL, then try this:

```
public class SSLVisualizer extends jFrame {
    public SSLVisualizer (SSL<?> ssl) {

    }
}
```

The question mark is a wildcard, and you can extend it to limit the amount of data types you can assign the class.

You can also assign your class a specific data type, like this:

```
public class SSLVisualizer<E> extends jFrame {
    public SSLVisualizer (SSL<E> ssl) {

    }
}
```